# How to refer custom font in html?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to create html screens. These are mockup screens and am not going to deploy in any application server. i have custom fonts created and i need to refer them through CSS.

My `index.html` and `fonts` folder are in below location.

```
D:\index.html
D:\fonts
```

i have below code in CSS file:

```
@font-face{font-family:"MyRegular";
src:url('fonts/mycotext_rg.eot');
src:url('fonts/mycotext_rg.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
    url('fonts/mycotext_rg.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/mycotext_rg.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/mycotext_rg.svg') format('svg');
font-weight:"normal"}
```

if i apply font-family the style is not applied. how can i refer the cutom fonts? Is my url refering fine or do i need to change?

Thanks!

Comment: `@font-face` merely *declares* the font for use in the stylesheet, it doesn't apply it to any element.

Answer (score 2):

Both the answers below are fine, and show you how to reference your font (by using the name declared by the `font-family` property declared in your `@font-face`, but as you're deploying locally you may also want to use the `local` property, which should allow you to reference fonts already installed on the system, before referring to an additional source. Using the Open Sans example, you could use:

```
src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(fonts/opensans-bold.woff) format('woff');
```

Then the font would only be downloaded from your URL **if** it wasn't already found locally.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the font-family value. In this case, "**MyRegular**".

Example:

The HTML:

```
<span class="special-font">Text</span>
```

The CSS:

```
.special-font { font: 1em "MyRegular", sans-serif; }
```

If you don't want to use a *shorthand* property like `font`, just use `font-family`:

```
.special-font { font-family: "MyRegular", sans-serif; }
```

You can add more than one font, separating them with coma.

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NDaN7/) with *Droid Sans* font.

About whether you are referencing correctly to your font, if you are in an external CSS file, your relative paths are bad! You must up one level in the web server directory. In your case:

```
../fonts/Your_Font
```

You can use this syntax (yes! Even in Windows OS). It's a good practice, because if you change your web page/web site/web application to another OS with a different filesystem (like UNIX) your paths will serve.

Cheers,
Leonardo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not going deploy in webserver. It is mock up screen. On click of index.html the webpage is displayed. I have the fonts locally. How can i refer them?

Answer (score 0):

try this

When u apply @font face write down example,

```
body{
font-family:'MyRegular';
}
```

Add this in your CSS & also `eot`, `svg`, `woff`, `ttf` font file in your CSS folder :

```
@font-face{font-family:"MyRegular";
src:url('fonts/mycotext_rg.eot');
src:url('fonts/mycotext_rg.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
    url('fonts/mycotext_rg.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/mycotext_rg.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/mycotext_rg.svg') format('svg');
font-weight:"normal"}
```

If `@font-face` in Chrome is not working, than apply the CSS below:

```
       @font-face{font-family:"MyRegular";
        src:url('fonts/mycotext_rg.eot');
        src:url('fonts/mycotext_rg.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
            url('fonts/mycotext_rg.svg') format('svg'),
            url('fonts/mycotext_rg.woff') format('woff'),
            url('fonts/mycotext_rg.ttf') format('truetype'),
            font-weight:"normal"

}
```